# Motivation and physical interpretation of the Laplace transform

Tags: differential-equations, fourier-transform, physics, laplace-transform

Concerning the one-sided Laplace transform,

$$\mathcal{L}\{f\}(s) = \int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st} dt$$

what is a motivation to come up with that formula? I am particularly interested in "physical" interpretations of the Laplace transform.

By comparison, the Fourier transform,

$$
\mathcal{F}\{f\}(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-i 2 \pi \xi x} dx
$$

can be motivated as a continuous decomposition into frequency modes, which is a physics-oriented interpretation: $\mathcal{F}\{f\}(\xi)$ tells you the amplitude of the Fourier mode $e^{-i 2 \pi \xi x}$ in the signal $f$.

I have not yet encountered any good explanation of how the Laplace transform formula arises. If the function $f$ vanishes on negative values, then $\mathcal{L}\{f\}(s) = \mathcal{F}\{f\}(s/(2\pi i))$, which is a nice relationship between the Laplace and Fourier transform, but not particularly insightful.

Comment: The [Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform) is another one to add to the library of transformations that are essentially group Fourier transforms (as opposed to the classical Fourier transform) in disguise.  This isn't much help for the one-sided Laplace transform, though.  I have always thought that, imprecisely speaking, the Laplace transform was intended to identify contributions of decaying real exponentials to a function, by converting them to poles.  But maybe that's too parochial a view.

Comment: @TomCopeland, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464191/motivation-and-physical-interpretation-of-the-laplace-transform#comment1205489_464191), sure, together with the rotation mentioned in the original question—that's the definition.  It doesn't immediately help me to understand the one-sided transform better, but that's almost certainly my failure; I'm sure you could give a useful description of how to extract an interesting motivation and/or physical transformation.

Comment: The Laplace and Fourier transforms coincide for integrable functions. But the Fourier transform isn't defined for locally integrable functions, while the Laplace transform is.

Comment: There is a unified interpretation of many topics in mathematical physics from a modern point of view.  The spectral theorem states that every (unbounded) self-adjoint operator on Hilbert space can be diagonalised--represented up to unitary equivalence as  multiplication by a measurable function on $L^2$ or $\ell^2$ (the discrete case).  With hindsight one can interpret some of the major projects of  the  19 th century giants (Fourier, Thomson, Tait,...) as the search for concrete expressions of this for the central p.d. operators (the laplacian on euclidean space, the torus, the sphere, ...).

Comment: In the continuous case, these are typically realised in the form of integral transforms, in the discrete one by expansions with respect orthogonal systems, typically the eigenvectors of the operators.    The Laplace transform carries out this task for the laplacian on the half-line.   This remark  overlaps with some of the earlier postings but does, I hope, place it in a general context

Comment: This may be too trivial to qualify as an answer, but a very simple physical interpretation of the Laplace transform is if you have a radioactive decay process which starts as a mixture of components with given specific activities, the activity as a function of time will follow the Laplace transform of the mixture composition (this is completely obvious from the definition). As exponential decays are common in physics (chemistry, biochemistry, etc.) this helps motivate its importance.

Answer (score 27):

The physical motivation for the Laplace transform is *causality*.

Consider the linear input-output relation
$$f_{\text{output}}(t)=\int_{0}^\infty R(t-t')f_{\text{input}}(t')\,dt'.$$
Causality dictates that the response function $R(t)$ is zero for $t<0$, to ensure that the output only depends on the input at earlier times.

Then if we know the Laplace transform $\hat{R}(s)$ of the response function (or transfer function), the output is related to the input by
$$\hat{f}_{\text{output}}(s)=\hat{R}(s)\hat{f}_{\text{input}}(s).$$
One could of course work instead with the Fourier transform, with the complication that the Fourier transform of a constant input only exists as a delta-function distribution (while the Laplace transform is simply $1/s$).

Comment: Isn't this the same for Fourier? Moreover, this is valid for any convolution, even if the kernel is non-causal.

Comment: @Quillo --- yes, one could write the input-output relation in terms of Fourier transforms of distributions --- the Laplace transform avoids that complication. Consider the constant unit input, which has Laplace transform $1/s$ and Fourier transform  $\pi\delta(\omega)+\text{P.V.}\,i/\omega$.

Comment: Let $H(x) =\frac{1}{2} +  \frac{sign(x)}{2}$, the Heaviside step function. With the OP's normalization, $FT_{x \to \xi }[1] = \delta(\xi)$,  $FT[\frac{sign(x)}{2}] = \frac{1}{2\pi i \xi}$, and $FT[H(t)]= \frac{\delta{(\xi)}}{2} + \frac{1}{2\pi i \xi}$. (To be a purist, P.V. for Cauchy principal value should be included). Note the substitution/rotation perspective $\xi \to \frac{s}{2\pi i}$ is not a bijection since for $s \neq 0$, $FT[H(t)]|_{\xi \to \frac{s}{2\pi i}} = FT[1]|_{\xi \to \frac{s}{2\pi i}} = FT[\frac{sign(x)}{2}] |_{\xi \to \frac{s}{2\pi i}}   = \frac{1}{s} = LPT[1]$.

Comment: Hey!!!!, which joker unilaterally deleted my correction to Carlo's answer! After some 20 or so people nodded their heads and said, "Oh, yeah, causality, that's the ticket!" and upvoted this answer, I commented to Carlo, "Shouldn't the lower limit be $0$ rather than $-\infty$? See the Laplace convolution theorem." He corrected the integral and thanked me. Who's the vandal that deleted these two comments?

Comment: Hi Tom, of course this wasn’t me, but I think this happens routinely as a matter of “housekeeping “: comments are deleted when an issue has been dealt with.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, I didn't suspect you. I don't approve of this 'housekeeping'. I deleted some of my own ealier comments to LSpice and included them in my answer, but the correction here provides an important lesson to astute newbies--answers and comments can be highly upvoted when clearly the upvoters don't fully understand the math but might be familiar with the slogans. Caveat emptor.

Comment: My correction also included the phrase "Laplace convolution theorem", an extremely important theorem and useful google search term to follow up on your answer, and was the only mention of convolution until or maybe other than Quillo's, outside my later answer.

Comment: Here is a reference: Fourès, Y.; Segal, I. E.
Causality and analyticity.
Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 78 (1955), 385–405.

Comment: To be clear, you can't get output from a causal system until you have input. Accordingly, the Laplace convolution reads as $f_{Out}(t) = H(t) \int_{0}^t R(t-t')f_{In}(t')dt'$.

Comment: I'm slightly puzzled: isn't the convolution relation between input and output not more an expression of linearity rather than causality? AFAIK The traditional account is that causality in a linear system means that the Fourier transform of the response kernel will obey the Kramers-Kronig relation.

Comment: without causality the Laplace transform of the response function would not give sufficient information (you would also need to know $R(t)$ for negative times, so you would take the Fourier transform, rather than the Laplace transform)

Comment: Zemanian in "Distribution Theory and Transform Analysis" discusses causality in section 10.3, but this doesn't imply the right-sided Laplace convolution theorem. The physical utility of the LPT is demonstrated in https://x-engineer.org/transfer-function/ in determing the transfer function for a blackbox knowing the output for a unit impulse input. The physical systems to which this analysis can be applied are linear, time-invariant, causal systems and the form of the Lpl convolution reflects this, but the causality property doesn't uniquely determine the math (e.g., the gamma fct integral).

Answer (score 25):

Besides the important physical motivation pointed out by [Carlo Beenakker](https://mathoverflow.net/a/464201/2383), there is another one, purely mathematical. Laplace transform is a generalization of a power series (and Dirichlet series).
In $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$, set $x=e^{-t}$, then
$$f(e^{-t})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_ne^{-nt}=\int_{0-}^\infty e^{-st}d\mu(s),$$
where $\mu$ is a discrete measure with atoms at non-negative integers, each atom of size $c_n$. If instead of a discrete measure you take a continuous one with density $F$, that is $d\mu(s)=F(s)ds$, you
obtain the classical Laplace integral. If $d\mu$ is any discrete measure, you obtain a Dirichlet series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n e^{-\lambda_n x}.$$

Another motivation is that Laplace transform is analytic, under much weaker assumptions on a function then those of analyticity of Fourier transform. This allows to generalize Fourier transform to a broader class of objects than Schwarz distributions.

For example, let $f$ be a locally integrable function satisfying only
$$f(x)=O(e^{\epsilon x})\quad\mbox{for every}\quad\epsilon>0.$$
Then the usual Fourier transform is not defined.
However both integrals
$$F_1(z)=\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-ixz}dx, \quad\mbox{and}\quad F_2(z)=-\int_{-\infty}^0 f(x)e^{-ixz}dx$$
are well defined and analytic: the first one for $z$ in the lower half-plane and the second one in the upper half-plane. The pair of analytic functions $(F_1,F_2)$ is called the Fourier transform in the sense of Carleman, and in the case when $f\in L^1$ that is usual Fourier transform exists, we have $\hat{f}=F_1-F_2$,
where boundary values of $F_1,F_2$ should be used.
When $f$ is a tempered distribution, the boundary values of $F_1,F_2$ still exist, as tempered distributions, and $\hat{f}=F_1-F_2$.

This idea is the basis of the theory of [hyperfunctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperfunction). $F_1$ and $F_2$ are essentially Laplace transforms, up to the substitution $z\mapsto iz$.

Comment: I thought the important mathematical motivation was that the $e^{-st}$ are eigenvectors for the differentiation operator.

Comment: @JP McCarthy: yes, this is also important, and there are several other motivations.

Answer (score 20):

Interest is continuously compounded at rate $r,$ so that if you deposit $\\\$1$ now it will be worth $\\\$e^{rx}$ at time $x.$ How much do you need to deposit now in order to withdraw at rate $\\\$f(x)$ per unit of time $x$ forever? The answer is
$$
(\mathcal Lf)(r) = \int_0^\infty f(x) e^{-rx}\, dx.
$$
In financial mathematics, this quantity is called the present value of a revenue stream.

Comment: In financial mathematics, the quantity displayed above is called the present value of a revenue stream.

Answer (score 16):

The Laplace transform is the fundamental operation encoding the canonical ensemble in statistical mechanics. It converts the density of states $d(\varepsilon )$ (a non-statistical concept) into the canonical partition function $Z(\beta)$, supplying the requisite
*Boltzmann* *factor* $e^{-\beta \varepsilon } $:
$$
Z(\beta ) = \int_0^\infty d\varepsilon \ d(\varepsilon) \, e^{-\beta \varepsilon }
$$

Comment: I'm puzzled: is there a reason to integrate only from $0$ to infinity? I would write $\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\epsilon \, d(\epsilon) e^{-\beta\epsilon}$, the density of states should then fall off sufficiently rapidly for negative energies to have a convergent integral, but I see no a priori reason for $d(\epsilon)$ to be identically zero for negative energies.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker - This is convention. A physical system must have a ground state, i.e., a lower bound on the support of $d(\epsilon )$. The choice of that lower bound is arbitrary, since the energy scale is only defined up to a constant shift. A natural choice for the lower  bound is zero. Any other choice will merely shift the free energy by a constant and thus be irrelevant for any statistical mechanical question.

Comment: Do you prefer $\text{“ }\epsilon\text{ ”}$ to $\text{“ }\varepsilon\text{ ”?} \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy - I'm happy with either. If you prefer the latter, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 6):

I will not discuss the uses of the Laplace transform.

Myself I think  of the analogy with sequences. A   sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is determined by its generating function  (convergence issues aside)
$$
A(s)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n s^n.
$$
By making the change in variables $s=e^\lambda$ we obtain its Laplace transform (again set aside convergence issues)
$$
L(\lambda)  =\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n e^{n\lambda}.
$$
Now think of the sequence as a signed measure on $[0,\infty)$
$$
\mu=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n\delta_n,
$$
where $\delta_n$ is the Dirac delta concentrated at $n$. Then
$$
L_\mu(\lambda)=\int_{\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}} e^{\lambda t}\mu[dt].
$$
This expression makes sense for any signed measure on $[0,\infty)$. If you now choose the measure $\mu$ to be of the form $\mu[dt]=f(t) dt$ you get  the Laplace transform of $f$.

Why would the Laplace transform determine a signed measure $\mu$ uniquely? Here's an argument when $\mu$ is finite.

Denote by $C_\infty([0,\infty))$ the space  of continuous functions $[0,\infty\to\mathbb{R}$ that have  a finite limit   at $\infty$. This is a Banach space with respect to the sup-norm. A finite measure  on $[0,\infty)$ is uniquely determined by  what it does to the functions in $C_\infty([0,\infty))$, i.e., the integrals
$$
\mu[f]=\int_{[0,\infty)} f(t)\mu[dt],\;\;f\in C_\infty([0,\infty)).
$$
The  family of functions $E_\lambda(t):=e^{\lambda t}$, $\lambda\leq 0$ spans a dense subspace  of $C_\infty([0,\infty)$. Thus $\mu$ is uniquely determined by the integrals
$$
L_\mu(\lambda) =\mu[E_\lambda],\;\;\lambda \leq 0.
$$

Answer (score 4):

From R. N. Bracewell, "The Fourier Transform and Applications", McGraw Hill 3rd ed., pp.381:

"Advantages of the Laplace transform over the Fourier transform for handling electrical transient and other problems are often quoted in books. The essential advantage of the Fourier transform is its physical interpretability -- as a spectrum, a diffraction pattern, and so on. Laplace transforms are not so interpretable, and once we take the Laplace transform of an equation we retain only a mathematical, not a physical, grasp of its meaning."

---

**EDIT**. I cited this excerpt, because this is where I personally found my answer to the question "is there a physical interpretation of the Laplace transform?". Bracewell gives a fairly clear and definite answer in the negative. As far as I know, this book is still a standard reference for science and engineering, so I stick to this.

Comment: Is this saying that there aren't physical advantages, or just that you have to look for them in other books?

Comment: @LSpice: I edited my answer to answer that. That excerpt gave me peace of mind: it clearly states that the Laplace transform does not have a physical interpretation, or if it has, it is far less important than the Fourier transform. That's a definite answer and it made me happy when I first found it. (I am a mathematician).

Comment: But see the other answers??

Comment: Very likely Bracewell used FT deconvolution when he did R&D on radars and imaging by radiotelescopes before 1954, well before he wrote his books on the FT. The book you mention was one of my my go to's when I started developing signal processing algorithms for advance radar imaging ages ago, but it ain't the say all on integral transforms.

Answer (score 4):

Re "I have not yet encountered any good explanation of how the Laplace transform formula arises."  I think it's useful to look at early origins of the LPT, relations to other transforms, and some specific  uses in operator calculus, analysis, physics, and combinatorics.

I)

Consider these delta function resolutions for the Fourier, Mellin, and Laplace transforms:

$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{\exp(2 \pi ifx)\exp(-2 \pi ify)df} = \delta(x-y),$$

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\sigma - i \infty}^{\sigma + i \infty} x^{-s} y^{s} ds= \delta(\ln(x)-\ln(y))= y \delta(x-y),$$

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\sigma - i \infty}^{\sigma + i \infty} e^{-xp} e^{yp} dp=\delta(x-y).$$

For me, the delta fct. results seem intuitive (also analogous to the orthogonality relationship for characters of character groups), and the eqns. encapsulate the properties of the transforms (try deriving the transform pairs and other relations from them, e.g., Plancherel, convolution, Poisson summation) and illustrate the transformations from one transform to another.

II}

Before the Fourier transform and before the LPT's use in probability theory by Laplace ([characteristic functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111970/meaning-of-a-quote-of-doubilet-rota-and-stanley-on-harmonic-analysis-and-combin/348735#348735)), in [projection for the orthogonal associated Laguerre polynomials](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97361/explaining-mukai-fourier-transforms-physically), and in electrical circuit theory and associated operational calculus beginning with Heaviside and Bromwich (see Operational Calculus by van der Pol and Bremmer and The Theory of Linear Operators by Harold Davis), Euler used the fundamental Laplace transform the Euler integral for the gamma function, a hybrid Mellin-Laplace transform, to develop his version of a fractional calculus. This can be couched the following way:

(From my notes in my response to the MO-Q "[What does Mellin inversion "really mean"?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79868/what-does-mellin-inversion-really-mean/79925#79925)", see also [this MSE-A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/why-is-eulers-gamma-function-the-best-extension-of-the-factorial-function-to/133194#133194));

The fundamental Laplace transform the iconic Euler integral for the gamma function for $Real(s) > 0$ ([easily extended](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13956/domain-of-the-gamma-function/132727#132727) to all complex $s$ with appeal to the inverse Mellin transform) is

$$  \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{s-1}}{(s-1)!} \; e^{-t\;p} \; dt = p^{-s}.$$

Note that when the integral is analytically continued, this provides an interpolation of the sequence $p^n$, the coefficients of the e.g.f. $e^{-tp}$, to $p^{-s}$, a Mellin transform interpolation, or example of [Ramanujan's master formula](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379428/ramanujans-master-formula-a-proof-and-relation-to-umbral-calculus)/heuristic.

The Euler integral is easily established by considering it as a modifed Mellin transform and then using the inverse modified Mellin transform to determine for $\sigma > 0$

$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\sigma -i \infty}^{\sigma + i \infty} \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)} p^{-s}  \frac{t^{-s}}{(-s)!}ds = e^{-pt}.$$

Generalizing from a variable $p$ to an operator, this suggests that a natural interpolation of the derivative as the fractional integro-derivative of a fractional calculus (Euler's) can be obtained by using the Euler-Laplace-Mellin transform to interpolate / extrapolate the sequence of derivatives $D_x^n = (\frac{\partial}{\partial x})^n$, the operator coefficients of the shift operator $\displaystyle e^{tD_x}$, to $D_x^{-s}$. Specifically, incorporating the Heaviside step function $H(t)$,

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{s-1}}{(s-1)!} \; e^{-tD_x} \; dt \; H(x) g(x) = D_x^{-s} H(x) g(x)$$

$$ = \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{s-1}}{(s-1)!} \; e^{-tD_x} \; H(x) g(x)\; dt$$

$$= \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{s-1}}{(s-1)!} \; H(x-t) \; g(x-t) dt \; = H(x) \int_0^x \frac{t^{s-1}}{(s-1)!}\; g(x-t) dt  ,$$

a convolution integral, such as Carlo presents.

Then acting on the power function for $\displaystyle \alpha > -1$, i.e., with $g(x) = x^{\alpha}$,

$$  \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{s-1}}{(s-1)!} \; H(x-t) \; (x-t)^\alpha dt =H(x) \int_0^x \frac{t^{s-1}}{(s-1)!} \; (x-t)^\alpha \; dt $$

$$ = \int_0^x \frac{t^{s-1}}{(s-1)!} \; \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^k \; x^{\alpha-k} \frac{\alpha!}{(\alpha-k)} \; \frac{t^k}{k!} \; dt$$

$$ = \frac{1}{(s-1)!} \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^k \; x^{\alpha-k} \binom{\alpha}{k} \; \frac{t^{s+k}}{s+k} \; |_{t=0}^{x}$$

$$ = x^{\alpha + s} \; (-s)! \; \sum_{k \ge 0} \; \binom{\alpha}{k} \; \frac{sin(\pi (s+k))}{\pi (s+k)} = x^{\alpha +s} \frac{\alpha!}{(\alpha+s)!} $$

$$ = D_x^{-s} x^\alpha \; ,$$

where the Heaviside step function is suppressed in the last two lines. (Another way to interpret this convolution is as a Mellin transform interpolation of the falling factorials, equivalent to the Euler integral for the Euler beta function--another instance of Ramanujan's master heuristic.)

The last summation converges for any complex $s$. So, we see that the Euler-Laplace-Mellin transform does give a continuation of the coefficients $ D_x^k$ of the shift op $e^{tD_x}$ to $ D_x^{-s}$ consistent with one version of fractional calculus, the Heaviside operational calculus, in agreement with [criteria proposed by Pincherle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355869/earliest-use-of-deconvolution-by-fourier-transforms), who was one of the pioneers of Mellin transform theory (as Mellin explicitly acknowledged).

(This is also related to the Fourier transform over a circle in the MO-Q "[Geometric interpretation of the half-derivative?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153542/geometric-interpretation-of-the-half-derivative)". In this way, the Fourier, Mellin, and Laplace transform are related. This can also be related to Newton series interpolation.)

The ultimate results can be extricated from the transform and convolution integrals by analytic continuation and extended to all complex $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with $D_x^{\beta} H(x)\frac{x^\alpha}{\alpha!} = H(x)\frac{x^{\alpha-\beta}}{(\alpha-\beta)!}$ and the operators saisfying the law of exponents $D_x^{a}D_x^{b}  = D_x^{a+b}$, realizing an extension of the Laplace convolution theorem (see, e.g., Generalized Functions by Gelfand and Shilov (Vol. I) or Kanwal).

The mathemage Euler took the initial step. Much later a cottage industry developed around the fractional calculus and Laplace transform after Heaviside's successes in the theory and applications of electrodynamics, Bromwich's parallel development of the Laplace transform pair, and Dirac's adoption of the delta function in quantum mechanics, leading to the the $i\epsilon$ cabbala of Feynman, the distribution theory of Schwartz, the algebraic operator calculus of Mikusinski, and the hyperfunctions of Yosida.

III)

A good deal of classical and quantum physics involving vibrational, or oscillatory, modes of confined systems can be characterized with the [confluent hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function) (CHGF), which can be defined in terms of Laplace transforms:

the Kummer CHGF $M(a,b,z)$ is given by

$$\frac{M(a+1,b+1,-z)}{b!} = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-zt}\frac{t^a}{a!} H(1-t)\frac{(1-t)^{b-a-1}}{(b-a-1)!}dt$$

$$ = D_{x=1}^{a-b}e^{-zx}\frac{x^a}{a!}$$

and the Tricomi CHGF $U(a,b,z))$, by

$$\frac{U(a+1,b+1,z)}{(b-a-1)!} = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-zt}\frac{t^a}{a!}\frac{(1+t)^{b-a-1}}{(b-a-1)!}dt.$$

(For the Kummer CHGF, see also [this MO-Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107159/pochhammer-symbol-of-a-differential-and-hypergeometric-polynomials/107191#107191), "The Kummer confluent hypergeometric function and some of its applications ..." by Georgiev et al., "The influence of elasticity on analysis: The classic heritage" by Truesdell, and the more recent "A physicist's guide to the solution of Kummer's equation and confluent hypergeometric functions" by Mathews Jr., Esrick, Teoh, and Freericks.)

The confluent hypergeometric functions include the families of Laguerre polynomials from which the Hermite polynomials can be constructed. These appear not only in quantum physics, probability theory, and analysis involving the heat, harmonic oscillator, and Schrodinger equations but also combinatorics. They also have associated ladder operators which form instances of a Graves/Lie/Heisenberg/Weyl algebra. Operators associated with the Laguerre polynomials can be related to a Witt-Lie algebra as well. OEIS A131758 has associations among the confluent hypergeometric functions and basic functions and number sequences arising in number theory and topology/characteristic classes. Special functions of the hypergeometric type are rife in group/representation theory and operational calculus, explored by Miller, Gilmore, Vilenkin, Carlitz, Al-Salam, Rota, Roman, Askey, Wilson, among others. Peruse also the book Hypergeometric Functions, My Love by Yoshida.

IV)

The Laplace transform also arises naturally in one method of deriving the Lagrange inversion formula for compositional inversion based on arguments surrounding the change of variables (for a suitable class of functions or Weierstrass approximations)

$$\int_{0}^\infty e^{\frac{-f(xt)}{x}} dt = \int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{x}e^{-\frac{t}{x}}df^{(-1)}(t)$$

with $f(x)$ and $f^{(-1)}(x)$ a compositional inverse pair about the origin.

See, e.g., my blog post with pdf "[The Laplace transform and compositional inversion](https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2022/05/23/the-laplace-transform-and-compositional-inversion/)" with links to earlier notes of mine on the same topic with different approaches and with explicit connections to partition polynomials of significance in combinatorics. This is also related to Hirzebruch genera.

Added 2/26/2024:

V)

I'll sketch some of Heaviside's legacy in using a formalism related to the LPT in characterizing the dynamics of electric circuits.

In the analysis of linear, time-ivariant (LTI), causal sytems, the action of a system on an input, or changes of the input induced by the system, can be modeled by differential equations as an intial value problem. The Laplace transforms of the derivatives of suitable functions are given by integration by parts as

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-pt} f'(t) dt = p\tilde{f}(p)-f(0),$$

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-pt} f''(t) dt = p^2\tilde{f}(p)-pf(0)-f'(0),$$

and so on with

$$\tilde{f}(p) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-pt} f(t) dt,$$

so the differential formulation of the action is changed into an algebraic formulation with initial conditions included.

The ratio of the LPT of the output to the LPT of the input is called the transfer function, equivalent to the LPT of the output for a unit impulse input, i.e., a Heaviside-Dirac delta function input. The output for a unit impulse input is naturally called the impulse response function (IRF).

[This website](https://x-engineer.org/transfer-function/) gives an example of a computation of the transfer function for a specific mechanical system.

[This pdf](https://eceweb1.rutgers.edu/%7Egajic/solmanual/slides/chapter4_SYS.pdf) from Linear Dynamic Systems and Signals by Zoran Gajic gives an example of computations for a specific electric circuit and further discussion.

Since the ratio of the LPTs for the input and output are sufficient to characterize such systems, the method can be applied to any 'blackbox' that represents the system but for which an explicit model of the system is not available. If the inverse LPT is available, the Laplace convolution theorem allows the system to be modelled as a Laplace convolution of the IRF with the input.

Of course, these considerations for systems analysis don't provide the fundamental LPT--the Euler integral for the gamma function--and I would also be at a loss to discern the inverse LPT from this perspective although I believe Heaviside could give the IRF in his own singular way.

Comment: The Euler integral for the gamma function also lies at the heart of Riemann's approach to his zeta function.

Comment: The term hyperfunctions is used differently by M. Sato and K. Yosida (see Operational Calculus - A Theory of Hyperfunctions by K. Yosida and An Introduction to Sato's Hyperfunctions by Morimoto), but both deal with distributions and generalized functions.

Comment: More on Heaviside's op calc at the website Dead Reckonongs: Heaviside's Operational Calculus (https://deadreckonings.com/2007/12/07/heavisides-operator-calculus/).

Comment: Some historical notes: "Leonard Euler's integral: A historical profile of the gamma function" by P. J. Davis (contains notes on the beta function convolution integral also)  (https://maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Chauvenet/Davis.pdf).

Comment: Note how the sinc function interpolation (called a cardinal series in the old days) of the binomial coefficient arises in evaluating the beta function integral, a Laplace convolution. Sinc function interpolation is related to the Fourier transform of band-limited signals (see the Shannon-Nyquist sampling theorem), and so the Laplace and Fourier transform are intimately intertwined in this way also.

Answer (score 1):

The following simple motivation for the formula was given in my undergrad class, which I hope I'm not misremembering:

Typically the way the Laplace transform arises in applications is when solving initial-value problems by transforming differential equations to polynomial equations. This technique was used extensively in the early theory of electrodynamics (as the Heaviside calculus), and it was only eventually justified using Laplace transforms.

Suppose one were looking for an integral transform $\mathcal{L}[f] = \int_a^bK(s,x)f(x)dx$  with the property that for all $s,$ $$\mathcal{L}[Df](s) = s\cdot \mathcal{L}[f](s).$$
The reason for this specific functional equation is hopefully clear: such a transform would take a differential equation to the 'obvious' associated polynomial. As to why an integral transform in the first place, one can motivate that in much the same way as the Fourier transform: we are decomposing $f$ into a sum of projections onto a one-parameter system of functions (see e.g. chapter 18 of Zorich's *Mathematical Analysis* for how this is done.)

A natural domain to work with for an IVP would be the positive real axis, and we then have by the above equation:
$$\mathcal{L}[Df]:=\int_0^\infty K(s,x)f'(x) dx = s\cdot \int_0^\infty K(s,x)f(x) dx = s\cdot \mathcal{L}[f](s)$$
Integrating by parts and solving will yield the kernel $K(s,x) = e^{-sx}$ (and a boundary term).